# The average value of each of a raffle participant's tickets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A raffle is being conducted with $t$ free tickets. Let the set of all tickets be denoted by $T = \{t_1, t_2, \dots, t_t\}$. The value of the ticket to reach placement $n$ is $v_n \geq 0$ (to clarify, this is the reward handed out for the ticket to reach placement $n$). A participant purchases $1 \leq p \leq t$ tickets. What is the average value of each of the participant's tickets?

**Update:** Isn't the solution as simple as this?
Because each ticket has the same probability of being assigned any of the values $v_1, \dots, v_t$, the average value of each ticket is
$$v = \frac{v_1 + \dots + v_t}{t}$$

Furthermore, if the tickets also had a fixed cost $c$, and the participant purchased $p$ tickets, I suppose that the participant's expected value would be
$$
p\Big(\frac{v_1+\dots+v_t}{t} - c\Big)
$$

Am I right?

Comment: What does "the value of the ticket to reach placement $n$" mean?

Comment: In the raffle, the set of all tickets are shuffled into a random order. The ticket that comes first has placement 1 and is worth $v_1$. The ticket that comes second has placement 2 and is worth $v_2$, etc.

Comment: So you just meant that the price of ticket $t_i$ is $v_i$?

Comment: No, the tickets are free. $v_1$ is the amount that is awarded to the ticket that reaches the first place in the raffle.

Comment: So...you mean, each ticket (which costs nothing at all) is handed a prize?  This is a truly bizarre raffle.  I think you should rewrite the post for clarity.  As it is, I feel like I am just trying to guess at the rules.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I also updated the post to now contain a question where the tickets have a fixed cost $c$. Was the tickets being free the only thing that was unclear or are there any other rules that you are currently guessing at?

Comment: Well, it appears that the prize for ticket $t_i$ need not be $v_i$, right?  Each ticket is (after purchase) assigned the prize randomly.  If that is the case, then I agree that each ticket has average value equal to the average value of the available prizes.

Comment: It looks correct

Comment: Indeed, the price of for a ticket $t_i$ does not need to be $v_i$. In my updated question, the price of all tickets are $c$. The reward granted by ticket $t_i$ is either $v_1$ or $v_2$ or ... $v_t$, depending on if the ticket get shuffled into first or second or ... or $t$th place, respectively.

Comment: Your suggested solution is correct.